# How to use pytest with subprocess?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

The following is a test. How to make this test fail if the `subprocess.run` results in an error?

```py
import pytest
import subprocess

@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_json", ["input.json"])
def test_main(input_json):
    subprocess.run(['python', 'main.py', input_json]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`subprocess.run` returns a [`CompletedProcess` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess), which you can inspect.

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "results in an error"—if it's the return code of the process being non-zero, you can check [`returncode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode).
If it's a specific error message being output, check [`stdout`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.stdout) or [`stderr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.stderr) instead.

For example:

```python
import pytest
import subprocess

@pytest.mark.parametrize("input_json", ["input.json"])
def test_main(input_json):
    completed_process = subprocess.run(['python', 'main.py', 'input_json']
    assert completed_process.returncode == 0
```

NB. You don't seem to use the parametrized argument `input_json` within your test function. Just an observation.

Comment: my bad, editing error. I actually use the parameterized argument in my test.

Comment: In case the process is in an infinite loop (or is a service), how do you ensure the process is shutdown in case you cancel the test progress (i.e. CTRL+C)?